# How can I copy/move saved data that is locked?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I want to move some saved data to my SD Card, but when I try to move or copy the data, the buttons appear gray, and if I use them the following message appears:

> This file cannot be copied/moved.

How can I move saved data that is locked?

The games are Just Dance 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2018.

(I'm using a Wii U, I have the Homebrew Channel installed on the vWii, and the Homebrew Launcher on the Wii U)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some games, mostly games that feature any kind of online connection, don't allow you to copy the savegame the normal way, to prevent you from using one friend code on multiple consoles. If you already have the Homebrew Channel installed, you could just use tools like the Savegame Manager GX to copy these games to an SD card.

However, the resulting copy will be in a different file format than it would be when copied by the System Menu, so you'd need to use the same software to copy it back on another console, or to restore it from the backup.